# Magento2 override core file

Tags: magento2

I am not able to override this file `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php` using preference.

```
<preference for="Companyname\Subtotalwithdiscount\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" type="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" />
```

Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try below code:**

> {{your name space}}/ {{Module name}}/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" type="Companyname\Subtotalwithdiscount\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" />
```

**There is sequencing issue in your code.**

**Note:** Make sure your `di.xml` file is locate at `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`.

**I hope it will help...!!!**

Comment: Not working it is the sales rule & I want to add a condition in loadAttributeOptions()

Comment: @Arjun : so what challange you are facing to add a condition in loadAttributeOptions() function ?

Comment: In this file Companyname\Subtotalwithdiscount\Model\Rule\Condition\Address I have added this function loadAttributeOptions(). Here I am doing echo 'aa';exit; . it is not refelcting. It is stll coming from vendor

Comment: @Arjun : can you tell me on which page this function are using?

Comment: Admin > Marketing > cart price rule > inside conditions

Comment: @Arjun: try clean  & flush cache once.

Comment: I did not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98032/discussion-between-balwant-singh-and-arjun).

Answer (score 0):

Your must use like below

```
<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" type="Companyname\Subtotalwithdiscount\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" />
```

Comment: Not working it is the sales rule & I want to add a condition in loadAttributeOptions()